# Session in association_proxy creator

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I use SQLAlchemy 0.5 and Python 2.6.6.

I want to select or create a referred object within an association_proxy's creator. My problem is, that I need a session for this, but I don't know where to get this in the creator callback.

*How can I use the session an object belongs to in one of its association proxy's creator?*

**What I've tried, which does not work**

I've found `session.object_session`, but don't have any object in the callback, unless it is part of my ORM object. If it is part of my object, the caller won't be called as a method (the first argument is the value of the proxy, not the object's reference):

```
class Event(ManagerBase):

    # If association_proxy calls this, 'self' is the key, not the
    # reference to the calling instance.
    def _field_find_or_create(self, key, val):
        session = session.object_session(self)
        field = session.query(Field).filter_by(name=key).first()
        if not field:
            field = Field(name=key)

        return EventFieldValue(field=field, value=val)

    fields = association_proxy("field_values", "value",
                               creator=_field_find_or_create)
```

Can I pass the object itself to the creators function? In this case I could call object_session on this object.

My project uses several sessions, because of this I have to determine the concrete session on execution of the creator.

Comment: This is also the case if you program in an asynchronous fashion (e.g. Tornado). In Tornado the session can never be global, lest transactions will be mixed up by different Handlers.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a validate method:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates, object_session

class Event(ManagerBase):
   value = relationship(FieldValue)    
   fields = association_proxy("field_values", "value",
                              creator=lambda group: FieldValue(value=value))

   @validates("field_values") 
   def _validate_field_values(self, key, value): 
       session = object_session(self) 
       if session is not None: 
           v = value.value 
           with session.no_autoflush: 
               uvalue = session.query(FieldValue) \ 
                   .filter_by(name=a) \ 
                   .first() 
               if uvalue: 
                   session.expunge(value) 
                   return ugroup 
       return value
```

The credits goes to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/RMDI1SnGhd0.

Comment: What's the purpose of @v = value.value@?

Answer (score 0):

This problem persists in SQLAlchemy 0.7 as well. I've had the same problem in a slightly different context. Because the associationproxy is a *Python descriptor* and descriptors operate on the class level you can't give the creator function a reference to a bound method (which operate on the instance level).

I arrived at the following solution:

1. within your creator function, create a new session from a global sessionmaker and fetch your objects
2. *expunge* your fetched objects immediately from this temporary session
3. close the session
4. return your objects

My code looks like this:

```
def find_object(name):                                                                                                                                                                                    
    # Because we can't get a grip on the actual session we instead use a global
    # session for querying this instance.
    session = Session()
    obj = Model.query(session).filter_by(name=name).first()
    # We also have to dump the reference to that session, so the created object
    # can be used on other sessions.
    session.expunge(obj)
    # We don't need that session any more.
    session.close()
    return obj
```